# How to use a format string with TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to test if a string is a valid timestamp according to a defined date format string.

I'm using `TO_TIMESTAMP` with a format string:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP(time_string,'DD/MON/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM')
```

however

```
TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(time_string,'DD/MON/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM')
```

gives an error.

How do I do this in snowflake?

Answer (score 1):

From snowflake docs:

`TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP` - Does not support the optional format argument supported by TO_TIMESTAMP / TO_TIMESTAMP_*.

I think only way you can do it using https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/parameters.html#timestamp-input-format and TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP e.g.

```
alter session set TIMESTAMP_INPUT_FORMAT = 'DD/MON/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM';
select TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP('DD/MON/YYYY:HH24:MI:SS TZHTZM')
```